# jquery slideUp/slideDown functions not animating

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm having trouble with `.slideup()` and `.slideDown()`

have a look at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7se2r/4/

Although the row is appearing and disappearing, I'm not seeing the animation of sliding up or down. any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There may be an issue with the fact that you are using a table, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With "tbody" you can use .show("slow") and .hide("slow"), but you can't do the sliding animation.

Sliding will work if you try it on a "div" for example.

Comment: Beat me to it +1 you can fade the row in/out but you cant slide it because <tbody> isn't affected by height.

Comment: I'm new to this site.  It looks like you have to be quick to answer!  I need to start posting some of my hard questions. Thanks Gallen!

Comment: I know this is old, but just in case - the animation will also not appear if applying using `display: table;`.

Answer (score 7):

Also, check you don't have CSS transitions set on your element, or globally to all elements. This will screw with your animations:

```
* {transition: all 0.1s ease;}
```

Comment: I was using a div element, so the accepted best answer didn't answer my question. This answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Can be done if you create a `div` layer inside your `td`s and animate that instead. It's not hard to programmatically add `div`s when creating your table.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jpillora/wU7RV/

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks.  I was injecting a new row via ajax and targeting the <tr> element with `slideDown()`, but targeting the div inside <td> did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Tbody can't be animated. Try to limit the height of Tbody and you'll see that it doesn't change the height.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the dimensions of a part of a table is only used as the minimum dimension, so the section of the table is immediately visible at full size, and the animation of the height has no effect.