# jQuery - slideup() and slidedown() only show and hide but don't animate

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery slideUp/slideDown functions not animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917248/jquery-slideup-slidedown-functions-not-animating)

I have multiple instances of slideup() and slidedown() in which they only show and hide but not with any animation.  Here is a jsfiddle of a simple example of what I am experiencing.

http://jsfiddle.net/DkhSQ/

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to animate `tbody`

Comment: I tried switching the <tbody></tbody> to <div></div> but it just stopped showing and hiding all together.  Is it okay to have a div around a set of <tr></tr>?  I know if you use a <form></form> tag around a set of <tr></tr> you get weird behavior.

Comment: The simple answer is... you can't animate a `tbody`...  The tech doesn't care whether or not you can change the markup...

Comment: Allright, I guess a regular show/hide will have to suffice.  Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned, table elements aren't supported efficiently enough by jQuery animations.

Based on your comment in another answer *"This is someone elses form, I'm just added this feature to it. Either way I am not well versed in css layout myself so a table it is for now"*, you can implement it with minimal markup change by splitting the table into two, encapsulating the `existingCustomer` table in a div (due to it being "display:block" by default). Then animate on that div.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/DkhSQ/4/) .

Comment: Ahh, I put it in a div before but with the div wrapped around the <tr></tr>'s.  I didn't think to split the table itself into two different tables with a div around the one table.  Thank you for your help, this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're trying to animate table elements. Table elements are not `display:block`, which `animate()` works best with.

Try wrapping the contents of what you are trying to animate in a div and animate the div instead...

Comment: This is someone elses form, I'm just added this feature to it.  Either way I am not well versed in css layout myself so a table it is for now.