# slideUp(), slideDown, show() and hide() not animating

Tags: jquery

I have used the following code for making accordion inside ul-li :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rr = true;
        $('ul.side > li.first-level > ul').hide();

        $('ul.side > li.first-level').click(function(){

            if(rr===true){
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown(150);
            rr = false;
            }

            else{
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp(150);
            rr = true;

            }

        });

    });
```

The problem is that the show-hide or slideUp-slideDown is working to show or hide the content, but nor animating as it should. Intead, i found that the more you increase the value or slideUp-down show-hide, the more delay it has in getting the elements show or hide. I found somewhere in this site a question, where he was having the same problem, but the answers told him to not to use tbody. i amusing ul-li. I even tried enclosing the ul-to be shown or hidden under a div, but it was the same. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xCHCF/ . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have the same problem as this question: [jQuery slideUp/slideDown animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917248/jquery-slideup-slidedown-functions-not-animating).

Comment: No, @speetje33, that link is got to do with tbody, i saw it before asking

Answer (score 1):

Its a CSS problem, you cant float the `<a>`, you have to set it block:

```
ul.side a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #494949;
    color: #000000;
    /* float : left; */
    display: block; <--
    padding: 15px 3%;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 94%;
}
```

And for the jquery part you could do it like this:

```
$('ul.side > li.first-level > ul').hide();
$('ul.side > li.first-level').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(250);
});
```

Here the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SfKR4/

---

Explanation why this happens, due a comment.

The animation is happing, you just can't see it, until its done!

The reason why its simple: **The magic of “overflow: hidden”** 
read this: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/ for more details about this effect!

When the `<ul>` starts to animate, jquery sets an `overflow:hidden;` on it, and starts to animate the `height` form 0 to his acctual `height`, when the heigth is reached, the `overflow:hidden;` is removed and the `<ul>` get's under the `<a>`.

Set in your fiddle, the width of the `<a>` to 50% and you will se excatly what is happening! Here it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/BEtU2/

Removing the `float`, and setting to `display:block;` removes the magic of `overflow:hidden;` and the `<ul>` its from the beginning under the `<a>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, @reyaner, but pls explain what removing float left or adding display block has got to do with not animating?