# slideToggle() on <tr> causes "jump"

Tags: jquery, html

When using jQuery `slideToggle()` function to show/hide data on a new row in a table it causes it to stutter. Yet, when using `slideToggle()` to show/hide a `<div>` it works very smoothly.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gLGUG/

jQuery code:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    $(".slideMe").slideToggle();
});

$(".slideMeDiv, button").click(function () {
    $(".slideMeDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="slideMe">
        <td>SlideDOWN</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button>Slide Div</button>

<div class="slideMeDiv">
    Slide me as well
</div>
```

Comment: `.slideToggle()` does work with table rows

Comment: Yes, I know it works... but if you look at my fiddle example, it causes a "stutter".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467336/jquery-how-to-use-slidedown-or-show-function-on-a-table-row

Comment: I mean that shutter. `slideToggle` doesn't support `tr` for some reason. you either have to slide it's contents or wrap it in a div.

Comment: Wrapping a `tr` in a `div` would be invalid HTML :)

Comment: Try this on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/gLGUG/3/

Comment: @limelights this still stutters for me

Comment: @97ldave check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mention the `border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` in the `table`

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

this will solve the jumping issue

Here is the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/gLGUG/2/)

---

Also for sliding effect you need to wrap your text with a div and place the div in-side the td

here is the updated [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/gLGUG/4)

Comment: its not jumping in chrome as well as

Comment: Although the stutter has stopped, there isn't a slide there anymore.

Comment: for slide you need to wrap your text with a div and place the div in side the td.

Answer (score 1):

I just do this in my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        $('.slideMe').slideToggle();
        $('.slideMe').css("display", "block")
    });
});
```

This stops the tr tag displaying as table-row which doesn't work with a slide toggle

Comment: Hmm, when I tried this I got nice sliding, but all my table cells squished over to the left.

Comment: @Michael12345 might have to give them fixed widths, maybe the cells themselves or just the table headers. Or not tried this but display as inline-block might work and you shouldn't have to change widths then.

Answer (score 0):

The slide toggle seems to work fine on a table row without any data inside its td's so if you slideToggle the content inside the td's then it should work.

try this:

```
function slideToggleRow(selector){
    $(selector).find("td").contents().slideToggle();
    $(selector).slideToggle();
}
```

used like this:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    slideToggleRow(".slideMe");
});
```

This should work, maybe not perfectly, but it's the best solution I have so far. If anyone finds a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For the restructured table:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
         <td>One Row</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Click me</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="slideMe">
         <td>
             <div class="tdDiv">SlideDOWN</div>
         </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

(1) Make sure you show both the "slideMe" tr and the "div" inside of the "slideMe" tr's td like this:

```
$('.slideMe').show();
$('.slideMe').find('.tdDiv').show();
```

(2) Use this code to toggle your slideMe row

```
 function toggleRow(selector){
   if($(selector).css('display') == "none"){
      $(selector).find('.tdDiv').slideDown(200);
      $(selector).slideDown(200);
   }
   else{
      $(selector).slideUp(200);
      $(selector).find('.tdDiv').slideUp(200);
   }
}
```

***Make sure the div inside the tr's td slides down BEFORE your tr slides down.

***Also, make sure the tr slides up BEFORE the div inside the tr's td slides up.

(3) Finally, you can call the toggleRow function:

```
 toggleRow($('.slideMe'));
```