# <tr> slideUp / slideDown causes jumps in column width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table, when clicking a TR, it slides open to show more data.
problem is the column width "stutters" slightly.

One solution I found was to set widths to each column, but I want the table to be fluid, and I can't set a width to all columns.

**HTML:**

```
    Click on a row for more info:
<table>
    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Age</p></td><td><p>Info</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>    
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
table{ width: 624px; border-collapse: collapse;}
tr {border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        }                    
    });
});
```

see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jcghqfau/1/

I've tried the solution suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105915/slidetoggle-on-tr-causes-jump) question, but it doesn't help the column widths.
setting `table-layout:fixed;` solves the jumping but prevents me from using fluid css.

Note: i need a cross browsers solution, including  IE8 and up.

Comment: You don't do slideToggle on TD/TRs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following style

```
td p {
 margin: 0 -1px;
}
```

I also added an updated sample

http://jsfiddle.net/jcghqfau/4/