# slideToggle does not animate on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in the head i have a button when the button is clicked i wnt the table rows to slide down for that i have used slideToggle(); but that is not working instead of the smooth slide effect it just shows & hide i tried slideToggle('slow') & slideToggle(500) but it did not work

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpre6q5p/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   

$("#submenu").hide();

$("#mbtn").click(function(){
    $("#submenu").slideToggle(500);
});

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [slideToggle in table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slideToggle does not work with table elements. Good news is, you don't need a table to build a menu, in fact this is how we do it in a more semantic way :

```
<nav class="menu">
  <span class="btn">Menu</span>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contributors</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can also pass on the javascript for the animation, and use CSS animations. Check out [this example](http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd).

Comment: Instead of a `<div>` you could use `<nav>` - this is what your linked example also does (for those who don't click through).

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery looks correct. I believe the issue is with using slideToggle on #submenu which is a tbody element. The slideToggle function works by reducing the elements height, over the specified time to 0, then display:none. To fix this simply apply display: block to #submenu.

```
#submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ready-made animation methods are for block-level
elements only. To wok with you can set tbody element as block level element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 1.10.2.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="mbtn" class="btn" style="text-align:center;"><h1>Menu</h1> </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="submenu" style="display:block">
    <tr><td>Projects</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contributers</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Submit project</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contact us</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#submenu").hide();
 $("#mbtn").click(function(){
    $("#submenu").slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
</script>
```