# SlideUp more elements as one element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make `slideUp()` table rows as a one element, and another rows as different element.

Example - I am having something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr> .. </tr> <!-- slideUp -->
  <tr> .. </tr> <!-- slideUp -->
  <tr> .. </tr> <!-- I will click on this -->
  <tr> .. </tr> <!-- slideUp -->
  <tr> .. </tr> <!-- slideUp -->
</table>
```

But **I don't want** to slide every row as element, but every rows group as one element

Another example: *P.S.: I can click on **any DIV!** After click every div which is behind will act as one element and every div after will act as one element*

```
<div>
  <div> .. </div> <!-- slideUp -->
  <div> .. </div> <!-- slideUp -->
  <div> .. </div> <!-- I will click on this -->
  <div> .. </div> <!-- slideUp -->
  <div> .. </div> <!-- slideUp -->
</div>
```

I want to have it acting like this **(but this is not valid HTML)**:

```
<table>
   <div class="this-will-slide-up> 
       <tr> .. </tr>
       <tr> .. </tr>
       <tr> .. </tr>
   </div>
   <div class="I-will-click-on-this>
       <tr> .. </tr>
   </div>
   <div class="this-will-slide-up> 
       <tr> .. </tr>
       <tr> .. </tr>
       <tr> .. </tr>
   </div>
</table>

<script>
   $('I-will-click-on-this').click(function() {
      $('this-will-slide-up').slideUp();
   });
<script>
```

**I need it dynamicaly, not staticaly, so I CAN'T surround elements with something, I can click on any row!!** I am looking for **Javascript** solution, not HTML.

I hope you will understand it :)
Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Invalid HTML as `table` can not have `div` as its direct child element. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Why not you change your html code with `divs`

Comment: @Satpal He wrote it he knows it, I think this is only for demonstration purpose

Comment: I don't know how to do it in HTML too. I need it dynamical. I will add example in divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

> Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.

```js
$('.I-will-click-on-this').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.I-will-click-on-this').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="I-will-click-on-this">
    I-will-click-on-this
  </div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div class="I-will-click-on-this">
    I-will-click-on-this
  </div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
  <div>xxxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for idea, but it is impossible to do this dynamically. I need javascript solution, not HTML :(

Comment: NIce! :) Tyvm I didn't know this function

Comment: Well, not at all. I don't see any "slide" animation. It just disapears without anymation. :o (but there should be some) It is exactly this thing, but I've to do the all rows to "slideUp" as one div.

Comment: @Jax-p, Its create problem with table rows see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row  I have updated answer with div

Comment: Great one! Work's perfectly now.