# Creating collapsible rows in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a table with collapsible rows in HTML using JS but its simply not working. Nothing happens when I click on the row with the class header1 Here's the code I've written:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr style="background-color: darkcyan;">
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
  <th>Column 4</th>
  <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>

<tr class="header1">
  <td colspan="5">Header Row</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

</table>

<script>
$('.header1').click(function(){
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle(1000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hi I checked it, it slow but it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/1870/

Comment: $(this).nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle(1000); instead of 1000 give 10 or something, the toggle occurs faster.

Comment: @Bhavana It seems to be working on Fiddle but when I put that exact code in a file and run it on either Chrome or Firefox it's simply not responding.

Comment: Have you added jquery Library properly to your project folder? Can you check your console what error is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.header1').click(function(){
$('.data').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
<tr style="background-color: darkcyan;">
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
  <th>Column 4</th>
  <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>

<tr class="header1">
  <td colspan="5">Header Row</td>
</tr>

<tr class="data">
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

<tr class="data">
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

</table>


</body>
```

Even your code is working. change it to '100' delay. why don't you give another class called 'data' in  tag where data are present.

```
<tr class="data">
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
```

then try this.

```
$('.header1').click(function(){
$('.data').slideToggle(100);
});
```

it will toggle all  tags with class "data".

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.header1').click(function(){
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle(10);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr style="background-color: darkcyan;">
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
  <th>Column 4</th>
  <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>

<tr class="header1">
  <td colspan="5">Header Row</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this code in w3schools editor it worked fine.
Added the jQuery reference .

Answer (score 0):

If you give a static height to your table rows the slideToggle is much more visible, but not quite as smooth as if you did it on a div. See the attached jsFiddle ([and hat tip to this post that showed me the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row)):

```js
$('.header1').click(function(){
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header1').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
    table tr td {
    border: 1px solid aqua;
    }

table tr {
height: 100px;
}

tr.header1 {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr style="background-color: darkcyan;">
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
  <th>Column 4</th>
  <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>

<tr class="header1">
  <td colspan="5">Header Row</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```